# How do I add point features from memory rather than a database or file?

Tags: arcobjects

I am embedding the MapControl into a C++ application. The application is tied to a proprietary, non-relational database. Therefore, linking the map control directly to GIS data is not feasible. Instead, I want to simply load my own point features into a Feature layer. I understand the mechanics of creating a Feature layer, but they appear to be tied to a data source of some type. How do I load feature data directly into the layer without pointing to a file or database? In other words, I want these features memory resident only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ScratchWorkspaceFactory, I'd use [InMemoryWorkspaceFactory](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriDataSourcesGDB/InMemoryWorkspaceFactory.htm).

You'll still need a featurelayer which will have a reference to the featureclass that resides in the inmemory workspace, as well as the symbology (IGeoFeatureLayer.Renderer) that defines how the information will be symbolized.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to display points, don't use a feature layer, but draw directly to the map.
Example: [here](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/Java/java/quickstarts/quickstart_code.htm#19)

If your points have associated data, you'll need to load them as features into a feature class (via [IFeatureClass.Insert](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esrigeodatabase/IFeatureClass_Insert.htm)) and attach the feature class to your feature layer. To do this, you'll need to create your own feature class first. Example code [here](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeodatabase/IFeatureWorkspace_CreateFeatureClass_Example.htm).

Not that this example uses a ShapeFileWorkspaceFactory to create a shapefile on disk to store the features, but in your case you can use a [ScratchWorkspaceFactory](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeodatabase/IFeatureWorkspace_CreateFeatureClass_Example.htm) to create a temp in-memory workspace, flushed when ArcMap closes.

Apologies for the various programming dialects within the links, but I hope they'll give you some starting points to work from.

Comment: MarkerElements is where I started, but the client needs the ability to select and interact with these points. I'll try the ScratchWorkspaceFactory and get back to you. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Your links helped me get the entirety of my code working as desired, but Kirk's answer was really what I was looking for. I wanted to load points in-memory without a harddrive footprint. The Scratch workspace creates a temporary access database. If I could, I would have made both posts the right answer. Thank you for your quick and thorough response.